# XSD Validation with schemaFactory: Cannot resolve the name 'ext:UBLExtensions' to a(n) 'element declaration' component

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, jaxp

Im trying to validate UBL invoice XML with the UBL invoice XSD file which imports some other XSD files. I read the docs and various SO questions that had the same problems. I however still have not found a fix for mine.

I create a basic validate method like so:

```
private Schema validate(InputStream[] schemas, LSResourceResolver lsResourceResolver) {
    Schema schema = null;
    // Convert InputStream[] to StreamSource[]
    StreamSource[] schemaStreamSources = new StreamSource[schemas.length];
    for(int index1=0 ; index1<schemas.length ; index1++)
        schemaStreamSources[index1] = new StreamSource(schemas[index1]);

    // Create a compiled Schema object.
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(lsResourceResolver);
    try {
        schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaStreamSources);
    } catch(SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "getCompiledSchema", ex);
    }

    return schema;
}
```

Then i create streams for all of the XSD files that get referenced in the xsd files and run the validate method like so:

```
    InputStream invoiceXSD = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/main/UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd");
    InputStream commonExt = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd");
    InputStream unqualified = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd");
    InputStream commonBasic = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd");
    InputStream qualified = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/UBL-QualifiedDatatypes-2.0.xsd");
    InputStream extContent = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/UBL-ExtensionContentDatatype-2.0.xsd");
    InputStream code1 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/CodeList_CurrencyCode_ISO_7_04.xsd");
    InputStream code2 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/CodeList_LanguageCode_ISO_7_04.xsd");
    InputStream code3 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/CodeList_MIMEMediaTypeCode_IANA_7_04.xsd");
    InputStream code4 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schemas/ubl20/common/CodeList_UnitCode_UNECE_7_04.xsd");

    InputStream[] streams = {extContent, code1, code2, code3,code4, unqualified,qualified, commonBasic, commonExt, invoiceXSD};

    validate(streams, null);
```

They are in the correct folder and when i remove the main invoiceXSD it all compiles fine, which indicates to me that the other file imports work as expected. Only the link between UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd and UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd (where the reference of the error actually exists, but cant be found) somehow does not work.

Im lost at this point, if someone has any experience on this topic and could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. Ive read things about implementing a custom LSResourceResolver which i might go ahead and try at this point. Im just clueless as to why my current implementation fails. Full stacktrace:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 44; columnNumber: 72; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ext:UBLExtensions' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4156)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4139)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1745)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDElementTraverser.java:170)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(XSDHandler.java:3612)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:636)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:572)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:538)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
at Main.validate(Main.java:49)
at Main.<init>(Main.java:35)
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```